# Rodar script python no android via um clique, extração de arquivos

Tags: android, python

Fala caras,
Como faço para converter um script feito em python para rodar no android?
Meu script é muito simples, somente para extrair um arquivo que sempre vai ficar no mesmo lugar, não preciso de uma interface gráfica para ele, somente preciso de um ícone que eu clique e ele faça essa extração do arquivo a ponto que qualquer leigo simplesmente clique no ícone.

Obrigado.

Aqui fiz o teste no windows.

```
'''
Programa para apagar a pasta com todo o conteúdo interno
e depois descompactar.
'''

import shutil

shutil.rmtree('C:\\teste')

import zipfile

fantasy_zip = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\\teste.zip')
fantasy_zip.extractall('C:\\')

fantasy_zip.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o **QPython** para rodar seu código pois ele funciona como uma **IDLE** dentro do seu dispositivo. 


 Entretanto, para "fazer um ícone" você precisa gerar um ".apk" e para isso existe o framework "**Buildozer**" que gera o "**.apk**" que você pode instalar no seu android.


Recapitulando, você deve:

1. Instalar o framework "**Buildozer**"
2. Criar o "**.apk**" com o mesmo
3. Instalar o **aplicativo** no seu **android**